# IBM xSeries 226 RAID and windows server 2003 setup

Tags: windows-server-2003, hardware-raid, ibm-xseries

I have an IBM  xSeries 226 server and I am trying to set up windows 2003 from its original cd. servers specifications are 1 cpu 4 Gb ram 72X3 scsi disks.

I dont know anything about servers this is my first try. I have some cd's like ServeRaid 7.10b but it doesnt boot on it (even I try to boot it by myself)

question is how can I config raid and set up windows 2003 ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to configure your RAID from BIOS setup that what kind of RAID you want to use. I think on that server you can use RAID 0,1,5. So after configuring it you will continue on installing your windows. Windows setup will detect the RAID and ask you for the RAID disk then you will need the raid CD that you mentioned. I think your server has a Floppy drive, so using your raid CD, you need to create the RAID floppy disk and use it during installing the windows. This floppy is like the driver for your RAID hardware. Then you can continue installing your windows.

Comment: it was my fault I put first time  ServeRAID Application CD, now I put ServeRAID Support CD. everything seems normal )